# How to show degree and apostrophe symbols in ColdFusion?

Tags: coldfusion

This is a statement in my ColdFusion:

> Normal temperature values 96.9-98.6Â°F will not trigger the alert. Celsius values from your hospitalâ€™s interface are converted to Fahrenheit for alert triggering.

I don't want the Â to come in between 98.6 and °F. And hospitalâ€™s should be hospital's. Please tell me if an escape sequence has to be used.

Comment: Where is this data coming from? What I mean is, are those characters being provided to your code from a database or web service or are you just outputting them directly in your code?  Where are they to be displayed?  On a web page, in a form, etc.  See [HTML Character Sets](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/default.asp) on what is needed to display special characters on web pages.

Comment: If this content is in the database, are you storing them as `varchar` or `nvarchar`? What database are you using? If you're not using a character data type that supports UTF-8, then the special characters will be lost when entered into the DB and there's not really a way to put them back without editing the content after changing the datatype of the column. You should then make sure to use the proper encoding function to wrap the text when you output those characters to the browser. Usually `encodeForHTML()`.

Comment: The HTML entity that I use for degrees is &deg;